# Powershell - How to find and return different lines of a file with different patterns?

Tags: powershell, match, multiline

I am looking to find a way to return all the lines that match different patterns on different lines. For example the first line may contain the 2 following patterns: 25.2.2021 SET_ACCESS_GROUPS and another line may contain 25.2.2021 DELETE_GROUP

I tried different things such as the following but it does not seem to find any matches.

```
[String]$criteria1 = (25.2.2021+ ".*" + SET_ACCESS_GROUPS  + ".*")
[String]$criteria2 = (25.2.2021+ ".*" + DELETE_GROUP + ".*")

Get-Content $pathOrigin| Select-String -Pattern $criteria1,$criteria2| Set-Content $pathDestination
```

Comment: This is where you should use Regex match. So, correct the requirement. Are these only two lines that you want to match in the string ?

Comment: please add a sample of the input file, the non-matches, and the desired matches.

Comment: I want regex match. Isn't it by default regex?I don't understand what you mean by: Are these only two lines that you want to match in the string ?

Answer (score 0):

**String** Method:

```
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($source) |
    Where-Object { $_.StartsWith('25.2.2021') } | # This makes fast first-pass filter
    Where-Object { $_.Contains('SET_ACCESS_GROUPS') -or $_.Contains('DELETE_GROUP') } | # Second-pass filter. Put strings in order how often they occured from often (leftmost) to rare (rightmost), this will speed up.
    Out-File -FilePath $target
```

**Like** method

```
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($source) |
    Where-Object { ($_ -like '25.2.2021*SET_ACCESS_GROUPS*') -or ($_ -like '25.2.2021*DELETE_GROUP*') } |
    Out-File -FilePath $target
```

**RegEx** Method:

```
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($source) |
    Where-Object { $_ -match '^25\.2\.2021.*(?:SET_ACCESS_GROUPS|DELETE_GROUP).*$' } |
    Out-File -FilePath $target
```

**RegEx Object** Method:.

```
$regEx = [regex]::new('^25\.2\.2021.*(?:SET_ACCESS_GROUPS|DELETE_GROUP).*$', 
    [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline -bor 
    [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase -bor 
    [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Compiled )
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($source) |
    Where-Object { $regEx.IsMatch($_) } |
    Out-File -FilePath $target
```

---

For huge amount of data there can be significant performance difference for those methods.   There may be better to use `-cLike` and `-cMatch` to case-sensitive search that is faster. RegEx method usually the slowest. RegEx Object method is optimized to *compile* expression once.